# VB.Net how to copy a page from MS Word with image

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I need to split a ms word document into a separate document for each page.
I have the following code, but it fails when a page ONLY contains an image.
For example.. page 1 and 2 contains text, page 3 and 4 contains a single image each. I need page 3 and 4 to be saved as a single document each as well as page 1 and 2
The line it fails on is:

```
WordApp.Selection.Copy()
```

With error:
**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: This method or property is not available because no text is selected.**

```
Private Sub ParseWordDoc(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal NewFileName As String)
        Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
        Dim BaseDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        Dim DestDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

        Dim intnumberOfPages As Integer
        Dim intNumberOfChars As String
        Dim intPage As Integer

        'Word Constants
        Const wdGoToPage = 1
        Const wdStory = 6
        Const wdExtend = 1
        Const wdCharacter = 1

        'Show WordApp
        WordApp.ShowMe()

        'Load Base Document
        BaseDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename)
        BaseDoc.Repaginate()

        'load base document
        BaseDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName)
        BaseDoc.Repaginate()

        'loop through pages
        intnumberOfPages = BaseDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number Of Pages").Value
        intNumberOfChars = BaseDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number Of Characters").Value

        For intPage = 1 To intnumberOfPages
            If intPage = intnumberOfPages Then
                WordApp.Selection.EndKey(wdStory)
            Else
                WordApp.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToPage, 2)
                Application.DoEvents()

                WordApp.Selection.MoveLeft(Unit:=wdCharacter, Count := 1)
            End If

            Application.DoEvents()

            WordApp.Selection.HomeKey(wdStory, wdExtend)
            Application.DoEvents()

            WordApp.Selection.Copy()
            Application.DoEvents()

            DestDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
            DestDoc.Activate()
            WordApp.Selection.Paste()
            DestDoc.SaveAs("E:\0099-Education\WordAutomate_Sln\WordAutomate\bin\Debug\" & NewFileName & intPage.ToString() & ".docx")
            DestDoc.Close()
            DestDoc = Nothing

            WordApp.Selection.GoTo(wdGoToPage, 2)
            Application.DoEvents()

            WordApp.Selection.HomeKey(wdStory, wdExtend)
            Application.DoEvents()

            WordApp.Selection.Delete()
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next

        BaseDoc.Close()
        BaseDoc = Nothing

        WordApp.Quit()
        WordApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: The error message is correct because that is exactly what your code appears to do: select some *characters* and copy those. You'll have to revise that strategy. At the very least you can make the error message go away by testing if there are any characters to be copied (and the error goes away but those pages will not be copied either).

Comment: Yes I know that the page contains no characters. What I need is a wokaround to copy pages that doesnt contain characters

Comment: Okay, then the root of the problem is that you are *not* copying 'pages'. Check if there is a "select all" equivalent in VBA that can also copy images (and other free-standing objects).